# Adobe Dreamweaver javascript syntax error enable

Tags: javascript, adobe, dreamweaver

I just installed Dreamweaver 2015, but I found that syntax error detection is disabled for **javascript** files.

it works on other extensions such as php files.

how can I enable it again on javascript files.